# Select only the rows where a value changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I'm struggling to write a query that returns all the rows where a column changes.

In the table below I want to go through all the records in date order and only select the rows where the amount is different from the previous one for that customer.

| CustomerId | InvoiceId | DateInvoice | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 209 | 9725772 | 2020-12-10 | 9.50 |
| 209 | 9725773 | 2021-01-15 | 1.50 |
| 209 | 9725774 | 2021-01-17 | 2.50 |
| 209 | 9725775 | 2021-01-19 | 3.50 |
| 209 | 9725776 | 2021-01-21 | 3.50 * |
| 209 | 9725777 | 2021-01-23 | 9.50 |
| 209 | 9725778 | 2021-01-25 | 9.50 * |
| 209 | 9725779 | 2021-01-25 | 3.50 |
| 210 | 9726132 | 2021-02-02 | 3.50 |
| 210 | 9726133 | 2021-03-02 | 9.50 |
| 210 | 9726134 | 2021-04-02 | 9.50 * |

I've added an asterisk to the Amount column for the rows that I don't want to return.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: If you were on a supported version of SQL Server (even one in extended support) this would be trivial... [LAG (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)/[LEAD (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Instead you'll need to use a self join to the prior row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use LAG() window function in a later than your version of SQL Server, but without it you can use a correlated subquery in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.Amount <> COALESCE(
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 t2.Amount
    FROM tablename t2
    WHERE t2.CustomerId = t1.CustomerId AND t2.DateInvoice < t1.DateInvoice
    ORDER BY t2.DateInvoice DESC
  ), -1)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c3cd486d2d6f90aade1784cc242675d2).
Results:

| CustomerId | InvoiceId | DateInvoice | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 209 | 9725772 | 2020-12-10 | 9.50 |
| 209 | 9725773 | 2021-01-15 | 1.50 |
| 209 | 9725774 | 2021-01-17 | 2.50 |
| 209 | 9725775 | 2021-01-19 | 3.50 |
| 209 | 9725777 | 2021-01-23 | 9.50 |
| 209 | 9725779 | 2021-01-25 | 3.50 |
| 210 | 9726132 | 2021-02-02 | 3.50 |
| 210 | 9726133 | 2021-03-02 | 9.50 |

Comment: That's really nice, thanks for your help, but is there a better way of doing the "-1" bit?  It's possible that the invoice amount could be -1, I guess I could put -9999999.

Comment: @fosbie You can change it to any number that you believe will never exist in the column Amount. I used COALESCE() instead of a subquery to shorten the code.

Comment: @fosbie check here the code with a subquery: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c31157f786dca322c5aba4ef20b08c54

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER` and `LEFT JOIN` to the prior row:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT CustomerId,
           InvoiceId,
           DateInvoice,
           Amount,
           ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY DateInvoice ASC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT C1.CustomerId,
       C1.InvoiceId,
       C1.DateInvoice,
       C1.Amount
FROM CTE C1
     LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.CustomerId = C2.CustomerId
                     AND C1.Amount = C2.Amount
                     AND C1.RN = C2.RN + 1
WHERE C2.CustomerId IS NULL;
```

Using forpas' sample data: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f668da7296dba92fe29822b36f9717ef)

But `LAG`/`LEAD` would be *way* easier.

Comment: This actually seems to perform much quicker than the other examples, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a way of doing it, but this looks horrible to me, there must be a more readable way of doing this.

```
SELECT t.CustomerId,
t.InvoiceId,
t.DateInvoice,
t.Amount,
(SELECT TOP 1 Amount 
 FROM #test t1 
 WHERE t1.CustomerId=t.CustomerId AND t1.DateInvoice<t.DateInvoice 
 ORDER BY DateInvoice DESC) AS PrevAmount
 FROM #test AS t
 WHERE ((SELECT TOP 1 Amount 
    FROM #test t1
    WHERE t1.CustomerId=t.CustomerId AND t1.DateInvoice<t.DateInvoice 
    ORDER BY DateInvoice DESC)) <> Amount 
 Or ((SELECT TOP 1 Amount 
 FROM #test t1 
 WHERE t1.CustomerId=t.CustomerId AND t1.DateInvoice<t.DateInvoice 
 ORDER BY DateInvoice DESC)) Is Null
```